# SQL Server - results from two tables that only exist in one

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables:

```
  Users             Messages
  ---------         ---------
[ FirstName ]     [ FirstName ]
[ LastName  ]     [ LastName  ]
[ SSN       ]     [ SSN       ]
                  [ Message   ]
```

I have the following query Microsoft SQL:

```
SELECT 
    t2.FirstName, 
    t2.LastName,
    t2.SSN 
FROM 
    [Messages] as t1
JOIN
    [User] as t2
ON
    t1.SSN = t2.SSN
```

What it gives me are the result that exist on both tables. What I need to to do is only pull records from Messages table if their SSN do not exist on Users table. I know that there is a second step involved but can't figure it out.

UPDATE: actually it still does not work. I have absolutely no NULL(s) in a database. All Records are populated with data. What I need is all records from Messages table that do not exist in Users table.

Example:

```
Users    [ 1 John     Smith   111-11-1111 ]
Users    [ 2 Jim      Tompson 999-99-9999 ]

Messages [ 1 John     Smith   111-11-1111 ]
Messages [ 2 Jim      Tompson 999-99-9999 ]
Messages [ 3 Angelina Jolie   888-88-8888 ]
```

### The result would be:

```
         [ 3 Angelina Jolie   888-88-8888 ]
```

Comment: Use a left join and add `where t2.ssn is null` oh, and you'll have to change the t2 selects to be t1.

Comment: Rather than duplicating the social it might be better to reference the userID in the Messages table and then join on the Users table if you need it.

Comment: Purely from a design standpoint SSN. isn't unique.  It gets reused after a few decades after death.  Not all people have SSN (that's a USA construct)

Comment: @mkross1983 thanks for advice I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @xQbert I understand your point, I know SSN gets reused but right now I am more concerned with getting the query to run will worry about the validation later. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- T1 instead of T2 in selects. You want records from messages not users. when we get our list you want data, not null values :D
- Join needs to be an outer join (Return ALL records from messages and only those in users that match since order of tables are messages then users, a left join will work.)
- Lastly since you know T2.ssn will be null when a match is not found, filter on it. Thus returning only the messages where SSN is not found in users.

.

```
SELECT 
    t1.FirstName, 
    t1.LastName,
    t1.SSN 
FROM 
    [Messages] as t1
LEFT JOIN
    [User] as t2
ON
    t1.SSN = t2.SSN 
WHERE
T2.ssn is null
```

Comment: In addition OP, you may find this guide helpful, I know I did: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: *nod* it's one of my FAVORITE (if not THE Favorite) visual aids when talking about SQL and treating/managing them as sets.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    messages m
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    users u
        WHERE   u.ssn = m.ssn
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
t2.FirstName, 
t2.LastName,
t2.SSN 
FROM 
[Messages] t2
WHERE
t2.SSN
NOT IN
(
 SELECT DISTINCT
 SSN
 FROM
 [Users]
)
```